# CollectionViewCell CardView Style

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, swift5

I have created a UICollectionView Inside a UITableViewCell using the code, and my intention is to create a card view style for each tile (for each CollectionViewCell), and something is off I'm not getting the card view effect properly. So far this is what I have done.

My CollectionViewCell Class as follow

```
  class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    let padding: CGFloat = 0
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit(){
        backgroundColor = .white
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
        contentView.addSubview(label)
        updateConstraints()
    }

    override func updateConstraints() {
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 0),
            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 0),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
            ])
        super.updateConstraints()
    }

    public let label: UILabel = {
        let v = UILabel()
        v.textColor = .darkText
        v.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5
        v.numberOfLines = 1
        return v
    }()
  }
```

And MyTableViewCell Class as follow

```
  class ReposTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    public lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = { [unowned self] in
    
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 10
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.register(CollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell")
        collectionView.isScrollEnabled = true
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        return collectionView
   }()


  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    commonInit()
  }

  override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    commonInit()
   
  }

  func commonInit(){
    contentView.addSubview(collectionView)
    updateConstraints()
  }


  func setCollectionViewDataSourceDelegate(dataSourceDelegate: UICollectionViewDataSource & UICollectionViewDelegate, forSection section: Int) {
    
    collectionView.delegate = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.dataSource = dataSourceDelegate
    collectionView.tag = section
    collectionView.reloadData()
    
  }
  override func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    let collectionCellHeight = 50
    let rows = 5 // 5: items per row
    let height = CGFloat(collectionCellHeight * rows)
    let width = contentView.frame.size.width
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
  }

   override func updateConstraints() {

    collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
                collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
                collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
                collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor),
        ])
    super.updateConstraints()
  }
}
```

Then I wrote an extension to the UIView

```
       func addShadow(){
                layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
                layer.borderColor  =  UIColor.clear.cgColor
                layer.borderWidth = 5.0
                layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
                layer.shadowColor =  UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
                layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
                layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width:5, height: 5)
                layer.masksToBounds = true
       }
```

And i access it as cell.contentView.addShadow()

Currently it looks like this without any vertical separator in between the tiles even.
What i want is separate card views for each tile (Jim and Paul)
What am I missing here??. Any help would much appreciate

[image]

Comment: Could you please add an image of cell that you are getting now?

Comment: Added @VishnuPrasannan

Comment: I think there is some issue with the way you are using the constraints.

Comment: can u suggest a better way

Comment: Could you try giving a view instead of content view. Change this (contentView.addShadow()) to something like cell.customView.addShadow()

Comment: is it possible something wrong with the sizeThatFits method